# Prove $\bigcup \{r(\cos(x), \sin(x)) : x \in \mathbb R\}\space \text{over all} \space r>0$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My idea for solving this question is to argue that 
$$\bigcup \{r(\cos(x), \sin(x)) : x \in \mathbb R\}\space \text{over all} \space r>0$$
is equal to $\mathbb R^2$ itself and thus open. Is this reasoning correct? If so, do you have any suggestions to make it more rigorous?

Comment: That is precisely what you should do.

Comment: Hint: For any element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider its representation in polar coordinates.

Comment: don't include the origin

Answer (score 0):

$\bigcup \{ (r\cos(x), r\sin(x)) : x \in \mathbb R \}$  is a circle with radius $r$.

$\bigcup \{(r\cos(x), r\sin(x)) : x \in \mathbb R, 0 < r \in \mathbb R \}= \Bbb R^2- \{(0,0)\}.$

$\bigcup \{(r\cos(x), r\sin(x)) : x \in \mathbb R\}$
over all $r > 0$, is simply indicating lots of circles.

Comment: What if I go like this: 1. Show every element in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be expressed as $(r \cos x, r \sin x)$ except for the origin. Since $\{(0,0)\} $ is closed, its compliment is open.

Comment: Would it be alright?

Answer (score 0):

If $(0,0)\ne (u,v)\in \Bbb R^2$ then let $r=\sqrt {u^2+v^2}.$ Now $r> 0.$ Let $u'=u/r $ and $v'=v/r.$ Since $u'^2+v'^2=1$  there exists $x\in \Bbb R$ with $(u',v')=(\cos x,\sin x).$ So $(u,v)=(r\cos x,r\sin x).$

There does not exist any $r\ne 0$ and any $x$ such that $(0,0)=(r\cos x,r\sin x)$ because otherwise $0=0^2+0^2=(r\cos x)^2+(r\sin x)^2=r^2((\cos x)^2+(\sin x)^2)=r^2(1)=r^2\ne 0.$

So the set in question is $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}.$